# bing api limit or restriction?

Tags: web-services, bing, bing-api

I am sorry for my English.

When I request:

```
[https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/News?$format=json&Market=%27en-US%27&Query=%27%22REGENERON+PHARMACEUTICALS%22+|+%22ACILAC%22+|+%22EYLEA%22+|+%22Regeneron%22+|+%22Age-related+Macular+Degeneration%22+|+%22Age-related+Macular+Degeneration+%28armd+Or+Amd%29%22+|+%22FENTANYL+CITRATE+PRESERVATIVE+FREE%22+|+%22Macular+Degeneration%22%27][1]
```

I have no any data in response.

But when I change request to:

```
[https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/News?$format=json&Market=%27en-US%27&Query=%27%22REGENERON+PHARMACEUTICALS+ACILAC%22+|+%22EYLEA%22+|+%22Regeneron%22+|+%22Age-related+Macular+Degeneration%22+|+%22Age-related+Macular+Degeneration+%28armd+Or+Amd%29%22+|+%22FENTANYL+CITRATE+PRESERVATIVE+FREE%22+|+%22Macular+Degeneration%22%27][2]
```

I have data in response.

Does anybody talk about restriction or limits in Query parameter?